# vertical header labels in QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtgui, qheaderview

I have a QTreeWidget with horizontal header labels at the moment and my intention is to draw 
**only** the headerLabels vertically and the rest horizontally.

I don't want to reimplement everything in QTreeWidgets's `paintEvent` method, so I am thinking of controlling the paintevent for the header labels, and then calling the superclass `paintevent`.

Something along the lines of this:

```
class MyTreeWidget: public QTreeWidget
{
  public void paintEvent (QPaintEvent *e)
  {
      ..... //Draw header labels vertically
      QTreeWidget::paintEvent(e);
  }
}
```

I've tried inserting a `\n` after each character when inserting headerLabels, but that's a really ugly hack and something I don't really want to do.

My problem is that I don't really know how to get a hold of the header items or how to paint them vertically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to create a `QHeaderView`-derived class, where you change the default implementation for `paintEvent( QPaintEvent* );`

and then install your custom `QHeaderView`-derived class as your horizontal header for your `MyTreeWidget` class.

Comment: how would I install a custom QHeaderView-derived class to be my horizontal header? At the moment I am setting headerLabels by using `QTreeWidget::setHeaderLabels(QStringList labels)`

Comment: Inside the constructor of your `QTreeWidget`-derived class do this, `setHeader( new MyCustomHeader( Qt::Horizontal, this ) );`

Comment: this is a good suggestion and it works, but I actually used a QStyle to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom `paintEvent()`, you could place the characters manually with `QPainter::DrawText()`. Either print them one-by-one and increase the `y` coordinate of the output each time, or maybe try to utilize `Qt::TextWordWrap` flag to make them automatically wrap on spaces (you will need to make a really narrow bounding rectangle in this case I believe, I haven't tried it).